# Inject repository into BackgroundService in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core and I have dependency injection setup in a way that `IRepository` is added as a scoped service. Everything works fine in request response scenario.

But I also added `BackgroundService` which is executed once every minute and need to take some fresh data. In order to do that I can't register `IRepository` as a singleton, I would like it to be created each time it is needed. What is the best option to do it in ASP.NET Core using the built-in IoC container?

Answer (score 1):

Inject `IServiceProvider` instead of the repository.  When needed, manually create a scope by calling the `CreateScope` (with `using` to dispose the service scope when leaving scope) and then use `GetRequiredService` to get an instance of your `IRepository` implementation.

This is all detailed with an example in Microsoft’s [page on background tasks and hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).  Example from that page:

```
public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> _logger;

    public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

        await DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedProcessingService = 
                scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using existing solutions for scheduled background tasks, e.g. [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

In scenarios like yours, I prefer to register a separate SchedulerService that controls tasks that must be started on a schedule or repeated every time interval, e.g., run a task each minute, as in your case.

Here is an example from my project:

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : BackgroundService
{
    private bool _isFirstRun = true;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        
        //We need to register all the jobs just once
        if (_isFirstRun)
        {
            var worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISchedulerWorker>();
            worker.Start();

            _isFirstIteration = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The simple implementation Scheduler worker where you can call your methods

```cs
public class SchedulerWorker(IRepository repository) : ISchedulerWorker
{
    public void Start()
    {
        //Register all the jobs you need to run
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(nameof(TakeFreshDataAsync), () => TakeFreshDataAsync(), Cron.Minutely);
    }

    public Task TakeFreshDataAsync() => repository.TakeFreshDataAsync();
}
```

And here is the registration of all the services in Program.cs:

```cs
services.AddScoped<ISchedulerWorker, SchedulerWorker>();
services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();

//You can use other providers; it is not recommended to use MemoryStorage for production
services.AddHangfire(config => { config.UseMemoryStorage(); });
```